# Running Netezza nzload on a Windows box

Tags: netezza

I am trying to run Netezza's command line tool nzload from my Windows laptop to load a csv (comma separated value) file to a Netezza database. 
I installed the Netezza client tools and have the executable (nzload.exe).

I tried the following:

```
nzload -h server.domain.com -u username -pw password -db DEVDB -t DRIVERS -delim ',' -df C:\Users\me\Desktop\Data\Test.csv

nzload -h server.domain.com -u username -pw password -db DEVDB -t DRIVERS -delim "," -df "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Data\Test.csv"
```

Nothing seems to work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you ping "server.domain.com" from your environment, i tried same command in my environment and it was successful. If you can send me more details may be i can help you.

Comment: Do you get a nzlog file output?  Any clues there?  Any stdout from the prompt?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider aginity for loads from ms windows. It has an import wizard and the like.

http://www.aginity.com/workbench/netezza/

should be a free download.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use the help flag (-h) to set the target hostname.  Try using the -host flag instead.

> D:>"c:\Program Files (x86)\IBM Netezza Tools\Bin\nzload" -db testdb
> -host 192.168.118.139 -u user -pw password -db testdb -t load_table -delim "," -df "d:\test.csv"
>
> Load session of table 'LOAD_TABLE' completed successfully